# How do I format task features with a one-hot task identification vector to ensure separate weight matrices for each task in multi-task RL?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, ai-design, meta-learning, multi-task-learning

I am on [Lecture 2](https://cs330.stanford.edu/slides/cs330_lec2.pdf) of [Stanford CS330 Multi-Task and Meta-learning](https://cs330.stanford.edu/), and on slide 10, the professor describes using a one-hot input vector to represent the task, and she also explained that there would be independent weight matrices for each task

*How is the input to a multi-task network encoded to allow the features of all the tasks to be associated with different weights?*

Would you have an input vector containing all the features for every task, and then multiply the input vectors by the task ID vector? Is there a more efficient way to approach this problem?

In other terms, here’s what I’m thinking:

```
network_input[i] = features[i] * task[i]
```

where `features` is a 2d matrix of feature vectors for every task, and `task` is a one-hot vector corresponding to the task number. Is that multiplicative conditioning?

Comment: I provided a link to the supposed lecture 2 of that course. Make sure that's the correct link. Also, maybe, to confirm, you could say which slide says what you say the professor says.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot.